# Get users Facebook ID for database

Tags: facebook, authentication

I need the following, any help would be much appreciated.

I Have a registration form.

It inputs the data Name | ID | DOB | TWITTER | FBID

When the user registers it asks for the above values. 
Twitter is easy as users can just put in their Twitter ID.
But I Need to get the users Facebook ID in the form.

What would be the best way to do this?
Could i use the 'Connect To Facebook" Feature.
All i need is the Facebook user ID so that i can use it when retiring graph data later on.

I have set up a Facebook Application and am using PHP with a MySQL database.

Thanks
Alex

Comment: Can put their Twitter ID?! what if I put a fake id? have you read the [twitter API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/auth)?

Answer (score 0):

Well, they have specific APIs for different functions. In your case none of their simple solutions work. You will probably need to use [Facebook's Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/.). You should take a look in their [PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/). It is a very useful tool. I used it once and it worked perfectly.
You will need to know much, before you get the users is. Also if you want to make that automatically, they will have to be logged in and they will have to confirm access to their personal data from your facebook app.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For any user data you wll need to get permission from user. 
You can use Facebook connect. 
Make the user log in and get access token, this access token is the key to all user data.
You can use this access token with graph API also.
[Check my blog](http://codethatworkedforme.blogspot.com/2011/08/facebook-connect.html).